# How can I run this powershell script in parallel?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

I have 100 databases in Exchange that I want to perform a task on. I might want to change the currently mounted server or something else.

When I run this command, each database is serially synced.  I would like to run them all in parallel.  How can I accomplish this?

```
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server nyc01| where Status -eq Failed | Suspend-MailboxDatabaseCopy
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server nyc01 | where Status -eq FailedAndSuspended | Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy- SourceServer nyc02 -DeleteExistingFiles:$true -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Have you tried using powershell workflows?

Comment: @Colyn1337 never heard of it! Will look into it

Comment: Specifically check out `foreach parallel` and `inlinescript`.  You'll leverage both of those.  Take note of scoping when using powershell workflows, specifically `$using:variable`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel

Answer (score 1):

IMO No need for workflow for that scenario, You can run the commands as a job and it will run in parallel,
to receive the job use the cmdlet receive-job.

The Cmdlets `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus`, `Suspend-MailboxDatabaseCopy` and `Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy` already has a bulit-in `-AsJob` Parameter, just add it and it will run as job in the background in parallel.

```
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server nyc01| where Status -eq Failed | Suspend-MailboxDatabaseCopy -AsJob
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server nyc01 | where Status -eq FailedAndSuspended | Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy -SourceServer nyc02 -DeleteExistingFiles:$true -Confirm:$false -AsJob
```